# Creating XML in C# with UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, xml

I know that there is a lot of tutorials about this and even answered questions here, but I have problem I'm trying to resolve for hours and I read almost everything here, but this still remains mistery for me. Please help:

I'm creating XML, and it's created, but the problem is that encoding is UTF-16, and it should be UTF-8. This is what I tried so far, but still is UTF-16:

```
        var xmlText = new StringBuilder();

        using (var xml = XmlWriter.Create(xmlText))
        {
            xml.WriteStartDocument();
            xml.WriteStartElement("Weather");


            if (model.ModuleList[0] != null)
            {
                foreach (var weather in model.ModuleList)
                {
                    var AddProperty = new Action<XmlWriter, ModuleModel>((a, forc) =>
                    {
                        xml.WriteStartElement("Forecast");
                        a.WriteElementString("Description", forc.Description);
                        a.WriteElementString("Date", forc.Date.ToString());
                        a.WriteElementString("MinTemp", forc.Min_Temp.ToString());
                        a.WriteElementString("MaxTemp", forc.Max_Temp.ToString());
                        a.WriteElementString("Pressure", forc.Pressure.ToString());
                        a.WriteElementString("Humidity", forc.Humidity.ToString());                           
                        xml.WriteEndElement();
                    });
                    AddProperty(xml, weather);
                }
            }             

            xml.WriteEndElement();
            xml.WriteEndDocument();
        }
        var xmlresult = xmlText.ToString();
```

How to set encoding to my XML to UTF-8? Please help...

Comment: You're writing the XML into a `StringWriter`. It's somewhat obvious that the encoding of a `StringWriter` would be the native string encoding that C# uses internally, which is UTF-16. Just write your XML to a UTF-8 `Writer`.

Comment: So I need to try different approach...will do... thanks.

Comment: @millimoose: nitpicking - strings do not have an encoding

Comment: @MiMo Seeing how strings ultimately have to be stored in a sequence of bytes, they should have *some* internal encoding, unless C# stores 32-bit code points directly. Since `char` is 2-bytes which does not cover all of Unicode, I doubt this.

Comment: Write it to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), and set the encoding explicitly using [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) with the [`XmlStream.Create(Stream, XmlWriterSettings)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162617.aspx) overload.

Comment: @MiMo Quoting [The Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx): " a single `char` (`System.Char`) cannot cover every character. This leads to the use of surrogates where characters above U+FFFF are represented in strings as two characters. Essentially, string uses the UTF-16 character encoding form." I'll see if I can show some example code where this leaks through the API.

Comment: @millimoose: internally there must be surely some encoding (even a full 32 bits value for each character is an encoding) - and maybe it even leaks somewhere, but it is an implementation detail - encoding appear when you write to file (or convert to sequence of bytes) - and in this case the default is actually UTF-8, not UTF-16.

Comment: @MiMo It really isn't just an implementation detail. For instance, `"\U0001F4A9".Length` is 2, which is incorrect. I also can't really find convenient methods that would let you work with `int` codepoints. I agree that you probably couldn't find enough programmers in the world who really need to care to get into the triple digits, but there you go.

Comment: @MiMo For comparison, Python 3 does this correctly: http://ideone.com/NzBtoG (Since Python 3.3 it uses 32-bit code points internally.) Java also uses 16-bit `char`s but it comes with a few methods that let you work with code points directly: http://ideone.com/Gbuygs. The .NET docs are also pretty up-front about using an internal encoding: "Each code point is encoded by using UTF-16 encoding, and the numeric value of each element of the encoding is represented by a Char object." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Characters)

Answer (score 1):

The result of your code is a string `xmlresult` - and strings do not have an encoding, they are always Unicode.

You use an encoding when you convert a string to a sequence of byte - so your problem is not in the piece of code you posted, but in the code you use to write that string to a file.

Something like this:

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.UTF8))
 {
     writer.Write(xmlresult);
 }
```

will write a UTF-8 file - where `filename` contains the path of the file.

If you need UTF-8 encoded bytes in memory use:

```
var utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xmlresult");
```

Comment: I actually need XML in UTF8 to store it in database. I'll try different approach then. I'm doing this first time so everything is new for me... Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is fileName in your example above?

Comment: Which is the data type of the database column you need to write the XML to? Which database are you using?

Comment: @user2710923 Most databases should support Unicode strings / text fields.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, and I set up XML type for this column.

Comment: The XML type in SQL Server handles the encoding internally - you don't have to do any conversion - and actually you don't even need to build a string, you can use an XmlReader directly.

Comment: Write now in my database I have for this column (when I get SELECT * FROM...) Syste.XML.XmlDocument. How do I know what elements does it have so I could check if it's OK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815836/how-do-you-read-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008