# Showing XML Data in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I have an xml file which shows data like this:

```
<learner>
   <name>Smith</name>
   <ULN>123456</ULN>
</learner>
<learner>
   <name>Jones</name>
   <ULN>56789</ULN>
</learner>
```

I have a table that stores the files as varchar (max) as I cannot upload directly as xml from my front end system.

I am able to read the file as an xml file by creating a table:

```
declare @ILRDATA table (Data xml) 

Insert into @ILRDATA (Data)
select FileUpload from ILRDATA.dbo.ILRUpload

select * from @ILRDATA
```

I now want to create a @table with the columns (Name varchar (50), ULN varchar (10))

I want to then populate this with the xml data

Can someone please help me before I waste a whole day trying to figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815836/how-do-you-read-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008), i think it contains what you want.

Comment: are you saying you _don't_ want to use the SQL Server XML datatype?

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    t.c.value('name[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as name,
    t.c.value('ULN[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as ULN
from @ILRDATA as d
    outer apply d.Data.nodes('learner') as t(c)
```

Comment: Hi Roman - I just get one line with null in each column. When I replace select FileUpload from ILRDATA.dbo.ILRUpload with the actual data I get the data display but this is not helpful as the actually uploaded file will change.

Comment: here's SQL fiddle with example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a9fc/2. Please check that data in the FileUpload is exact the same you've shown in the question