# Parsing out a single column into multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I have a column with a "Payload" of data. It represents a dynamic field where an application pulls all of the data from a source (API, stored procedure, etc) into one column in one table. Each payload can be a different set of columns, so I cannot land the information into a table. But I need my team to be able to pull out the information. The delimiters are static. 
Example: Source table looks like this

```
ID    Payload
123   {"Transaction":"123456","Transaction2":"789123"}
124   {"Transaction":"123457","Transaction2":"789124"}
```

I would like the final output to be:

```
ID     Transaction   Transaction2
123    123456        789123
124    123457        789124
```

I have a split function that I can pass through twice to get me the following:

```
ID   SplitID      Split               SplitID2    Split 2
123  1            transaction:123456  1           transaction
123  1            transaction:123456  2           123456
123  2            transaction2:789123 1           transaction2
123  2            transaction2:789123 2           789123
124  1...
```

So now I need to flatten this without using dynamic SQL... OR putting this in a place where a team of 20 can consume and use on a regular basis with NO persisting tables, etc...

Edit: We currently have SQL 2012. We are a few months out from 2017. Sorry for the lack of documenting.

Comment: What SQL Server version? 2016 has built in JSON functionality.

Comment: Not sure if you need your split function.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql     you might have luck with the xml reader here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815836/how-do-you-read-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008   (of course dfundako beats me to the post while I look up links ;) )

Comment: @dfundako - 2012. :(  We will have 2017 in a few months though. Looking forward to using Json

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server 2016, you can use [`json_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql):

```
select  id
,       json_value(payload, '$.Transaction')
,       json_value(payload, '$.Transaction2')
from    t1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b2bf2/5/0)

For earlier versions of SQL Server, you'd need a CLR UDF, like [JSON Select](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/JSON/128550/).

Comment: @Twelfth Yeah, JSON started in 2016

Comment: sure beats trying to parse it out with substring functions

Comment: SQL 2012 unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the sense that you are not on 2016+

SQL Server is declarative by design, so getting variable columns without going dynamic is not possible.

If you have a maximumn number of columns, consider the following:

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select CleanString = replace(replace(replace(replace(Payload,'{',''),',',':'),'"',''),'}','') ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[10]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[12]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[14]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[16]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[18]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(CleanString,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5    Pos6    Pos7    Pos8    Pos9  
123 123456  789123  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
124 123457  789124  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If that document would be slightly more polished for a JSON and you run SQL Server 2016+..:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[  
      {"ID" : "123", "Payload" : {"Transaction":"123456","Transaction2":"789123"}},
      {"ID" : 124, "Payload" : {"Transaction":"123457","Transaction2":"789124"}}
 ]'  

SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (id int '$.ID',  
        Transaction1 int '$.Payload.Transaction',
        Transaction2 int '$.Payload.Transaction2'

        )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you DON'T have SQL Server 2016 or above, then the answer is a bit more complicated. What I would do is stop after the first split (don't split the name and the value into separate rows), so your table looks like:

```
ID   SplitID      Split               
123  1            transaction:123456  
123  2            transaction2:789123 
124  1...
```

...one transaction/row, one row/transaction. Assuming that the split did remove the quotes, as it appears, then something like the following should work (untested):

```
select  id
    , Transaction
    , Transaction2
FROM
    (SELECT LEFT(Split, CHARINDEX(':', Split)-1) AS FieldName
         SUBSTRING(Split, CHARINDEX(':', Split)+1,999) AS FieldValue
         FROM udf.splittable(t1)) as sourcetable
PIVOT
(
    MIN(FieldValue)
    FOR FieldName IN ([Transaction], [Transaction2])
) AS PivotTable;
```

...but yeah, if you have 2016 or higher, go with the JSON route mentioned in other answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can try [RegexAssembly](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/)

```
    declare  @valcheck table
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    payload varchar(100)
)

insert into @valcheck(payload) 
values('{"Transaction":"123456","Transaction2":"789123"}'),
      ('{"Transaction":"123457","Transaction2":"789124"}')


select id, [1] as 'Transaction1',[2] as 'Transaction2' from @valcheck a
cross apply(
            select [1],[2] from
                (select dbo.RegExMatch('(?<=:")\d+',Match,1) as match, 
                        row_number()over(order by (select 0)) as rn 
                        from dbo.RegExSplit(',',a.payload,1)) as D
        pivot
           (max(match) for rn in ([1],[2]) ) as pivoteed
)c
```