# SQL Server: Stored Procedure coding

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a *staging* table containing a varchar(1000) column which contains strings like

some text\more text\text string again\still another string\one more string.

The records can contain either 8 or 9 occurrences of the `\`, which I can readily determine

What I need to do is insert the staged records into a **real** Table, with each string inserted into a specific column.  So I need to determine

> If string contains 8 fields, then insert into these target table columns
>     else if string contains 9 fields, then insert into these target table columns
>     otherwise skip

I am quite new to Procedural code and don't understand how to implement this *If, Then, Else* logic.  Can anyone give me hand?

Comment: Show us the code you wrote when you attempted this and found it to not produce what you wanted.

Comment: Sure we can help. Can you post some information so we have a chance? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541435/parsing-out-a-single-column-into-multiple/49542466#49542466

Comment: Is there some reason why this isn't as simple as googling `SQL Server IF ELSE`?

Comment: Ok... firstly, your question isn't particularly clear. That's ok, but bear in mind its hard to help. One suggestion I would make however is that SQL is not well suited to parsing strings (ie. delimited by slashes). Have a look to functions that can turn your string into a datatable, and you could do joins and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code can help you to solve your probem.

```
create table myTable (
      c1  varchar(1024)
    , c2  varchar(1024)
    , c3  varchar(1024)
    , c4  varchar(1024)
    , c5  varchar(1024)
    , c6  varchar(1024)
    , c7  varchar(1024)
    , c8  varchar(1024)
    , c11  varchar(1024)
    , c12  varchar(1024)
    , c13  varchar(1024)
    , c14  varchar(1024)
    , c15  varchar(1024)
    , c16  varchar(1024)
    , c17  varchar(1024)
    , c18  varchar(1024)
    , c19  varchar(1024)
);

declare @string as varchar(1024) = 'some text\more text\text string again\still another string\one more string\s6\s7\s8';
declare @col_values as table ( idx int identity(1,1), value varchar(1024) );
declare @row_cnt as integer

-- Split the string into separate values
insert into @col_values
select t.value  from string_split (@string,'\') t;
-- Get number of values in splited string
set @row_cnt =  @@ROWCOUNT

if @row_cnt = 8
    begin
        insert into myTable(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8)
            values ( (select value from @col_values where idx = 1)
                   , (select value from @col_values where idx = 2)
                   , (select value from @col_values where idx = 3)
                   , (select value from @col_values where idx = 4)
                   , (select value from @col_values where idx = 5)
                   , (select value from @col_values where idx = 6)
                   , (select value from @col_values where idx = 7)
                   , (select value from @col_values where idx = 8)
                   );

    end;
else
    begin
        if @row_cnt = 9 
            begin
                insert into myTable(c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19)
                    values ( (select value from @col_values where idx = 1)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 2)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 3)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 4)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 5)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 6)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 7)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 8)
                           , (select value from @col_values where idx = 9)
                           );
            end;
        else
            -- If there is no 8 or 9 values then raise an exception
            raiserror(N'Number of elements is %d',16,0,@row_cnt);
    end;

select * from myTable ;

drop table myTable ;
go
```