# Pass HTML table as parameter to Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have an HTML table from which I want to record data into SQL database. I would like use a stored procedure for that. As of now, I am reading table into key/value object. I would like to use that object as parameter in  SQL stored procedure. Its my understanding that the best way to do it, is to convert Javascript Object to XML. Which I can do using this:

```
function objectToXml(object) {
var xml = '';
for (var prop in object) {
    if (!object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (object[prop] == undefined)
        continue;
    xml += "<" + prop + ">";
    console.log(object[prop], prop, typeof prop)
    if (typeof object[prop] == "object")
        xml += objectToXml(new Object(object[prop]));
    else
        xml += object[prop];
    xml += "</" + prop + ">";
}
return xml;
}
```

That function returns XML string in the following format:

```
<0><key1>value1</key1>....<keyN>valueN</keyN></0><1><key1>value1a</key1>....<keyN>valueNa</keyN></1>..
```

I can pass that string into SQL stored procedure but struggling after that. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: This answer may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815836/how-do-you-read-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez. It did. Thank You